# UITextField keyboard. How to disable force touch?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

I faced with an interesting problem. In my app, I have some `UITextFields` that could contain only one character inside.
From iPhone 6s (iOS 9) Apple has introduced a cool feature related with force touch on keyboard text field:

[image: gif]

<sub><sup><sub><sup>http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/iphone-keyboard-trackpad.mov.gif</sup></sub></sup></sub>

In my case when the text field can contain only one character is completely useless and can be very misunderstanding.

I went through the `UITextField` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield) and I haven't found anything that could help me.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? Is it possible?

Thanks!

***UPDATE***

Related with @dmorrow answer:

Setting the `isSecureTextEntry` to true disables that feature, but in my case I want to see the input text. So the `isSecureTextEntry` must be `false`

Comment: "As we know" Well, I sure didn't know!

Comment: So now you are :)

Comment: Can you clarify why the interaction is 'completely useless'?  Perhaps there is a way to change your interface so that this isn't a problem.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, my text fields could contain only ONE character. The whole control looks like this https://github.com/SethSky/KOPinCodeView/raw/master/KOPinCodeView/Assets/pin_code_view.gif?raw=true.
Otherwise, I spent some time to disable this without any success, so I thought it would be nice to ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested, and `textField.isSecureTextEntry = true` disables this feature.
I'm not sure how you are switching your input from number to •, but if you just use the native password input you'll get the result you need.

### New Idea

What if you used a hidden textfield for the input, with `isSecureTextEntry = true`.  Each of your input fields would actually just be a `UIButton`.  On tapping the button, the hidden textfield would become first responder.  On text input, you could set the label of the button and jump to the next button as you are doing now.  Any time the user taps the button, it would clear the input and allow them to type again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's interesting that `isSecureTextEntry`disables this feature. But in my case i want to see the input so the `isSecureTextEntry` must be false.

Comment: Your sample shows the input being replaced with •.  Is this only after the next input is triggered?

Comment: In my case, I don't want to hide input. In this sample, I just want to show that my text field is one-character input. Your 'new idea' is very interesting but it's kind of workaround. I want to know if it is possible to disable force touch on keyboard without hiding the input.